# What is the difference between having one data file or multiple data files for a tablespace?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c

Oracle allow to create table space with multiple data files. what is the different with one data file size 1TB and 2 data files 500GB each? Is it any performance gain?

Comment: The answer depends on whether or not you're using ASM.  Also, the question doesn't appear to have realistic data file sizes - I think the max size is 128 gigabytes.  If you have terabyte data files then you're using bigfiles, which only allow one data file per tablespace.

Answer (score 3):

Performance? Could be. If you have one large (or two smaller) datafiles on the same hard disk, that will probably run somewhat slower than having two smaller datafiles on **diferent** hard disks. You know, you & me accessing data at the same time. HDD head will have to "jump" from one place to another to send data to both of us. If those were two disks, there's a chance that each disk will provide data separately and that would be faster.